# How to scroll images vertically in blackberry

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, java-me

All the screens I've designed for BlackBerry so far I set the position coordinates statically, without the need of a vertical scroll.

I do not understand how to use this vertical manager to scroll and see the list.

Answer (score 0):

We have to create vertical field manager as follow

```
VerticalFieldManager manager=
    new VerticalFieldManager(
         Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | 
         Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR );
```

to scroll fields in vertical field manager.
The following link will also help you.

[How to set a ScrollBar to the VerticalFieldManager in Blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141812/how-to-set-a-scrollbar-to-the-verticalfieldmanager-in-blackberry)